# SharePoint Online CSOM/PowerShell Permissions

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, permissions, csom

I have problems to list lists permissions using CSOM/PowerShell.

Variables / filters

```
$spSiteUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com"
```

Getting credentials

```
if($cred -eq $null)
{
    $cred = Get-Credential
}
```

Loading Assemblies

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null
```

Connecting into SharePoint and showing site title

```
Write-Host "Connecting to SharePoint"
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($spSiteUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($cred.UserName, $cred.Password)

$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Site Name : $($web.Title)"
```

Function listing "useful" applications

```
function getApps($web)
{
    $appsArray = @()

    $apps = $web.Lists
    $ctx.Load($apps)   

    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()  

    Write-Host "List of aplications : "
    foreach($app in $apps){  
        if($app.Hidden -eq $false)
        {
            $item = New-Object PSObject
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col1' -Value $($app.Title)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col2' -Value $($app.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col3' -Value $($app.RoleAssignments)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col4' -Value $($app.BrowserFileHandling)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col5' -Value $($app.EffectiveBasePermissions)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col6' -Value $($app.Fields)
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Col7' -Value $($app.WorkflowAssociations)
            $appsArray += $item
        }
    } 
    $appsArray | Format-Table
}
```

Calling the function

```
getApps($web)
```

My problem is that :

- $app.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
- $app.RoleAssignments
- $app.BrowserFileHandling
- $app.EffectiveBasePermissions
- $app.Fields
- $app.WorkflowAssociations

Return me errors

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the  request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested..

Answer (score 0):

The exception

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

Typically means that the property you are trying to work with (e.g. HasUniqueRoleAssignments) was not retrieved from the server yet.

You probably need an additional ExecuteQuery to load each app

```
foreach($app in $apps){  
if($app.Hidden -eq $false)
{
 $ctx.Load($app)
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

You will eventually notice that some properties can't be retrieved with regular csom api (such as HasUniqueRoleAssignments) and for those you can use Gary's powershell, giving you the possibility to do what you otherwise would use linq

```
foreach($app in $apps){  
if($app.Hidden -eq $false)
{
 $ctx.Load($app)
 Load-CSOMProperties -object $app -propertyNames @("HasUniqueRoleAssignments")
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

https://gist.github.com/glapointe/cc75574a1d4a225f401b#file-load-csomproperties-ps1

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126221/spo-retrieve-hasuniqueroleassignements-property-using-powershell